# Google Charts: How can change default selected value in controlType: CategoryFilter of ControlWrapper

Tags: javascript, visualization, google-visualization

I have a category filter for choosing a date which is bind to a pie chart. Currently it is showing the caption as default ('Choose a value'). I want to set the its default value to one of the contained values, say last date.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A little late but checkout this example:

```
  // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
  google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
  // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
  // draws it.
  function drawChart() {

    // Create the data table.
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['2004',  1000,      400],
      ['2005',  1170,      460],
      ['2006',  660,       1120],
      ['2007',  1030,      540]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
    //============All=U=Need============
    chart.setSelection([{'column': 1}]);
    //============All=U=Need============
  }
```

:D